# Find the smallest area (minimum) of a triangle circumscribing a circle with radius r, using calculus.

Tags: calculus

[image]

I am not sure how to represent this in a diagram so that I may solve it. 
ANY HELP, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Let the triangle be $ABC$ such that $AB=AC$, $\angle B = \angle C$. Draw the triangle so that $A$ lies on the x-axis, and $B$, $C$ are symmetric.

Answer (score 1):

Draw a diagram with triangle $APB$ (which has $AP = PB$) circumscribing circle $O$, which meets the triangle at points $'P$ on $AB$,  $'A$ on $PB$, and  $'B$ on $AP$.

Let $\angle APB = 2 \theta$. Then because the sum of the angles in the triangle is $\pi$,  $\angle PAB = \angle PBA = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.

And triangle $POA'$ is a right triangle, with $OA' = r$ and $\angle OPA' = \theta$.  Trig tells us that $OP = r\csc\theta$

Then $OP' = r( 1+\csc\theta)$ and now look at right triangle $PP'A$, in which 
$$
AP' = r( 1+\csc\theta) \tan \theta$
$$
The area of triangle $APB$ is 
$$AP' \cdot PP' = r^2 ( 1+\csc\theta)^2 \tan \theta$$
Since $r$ is fixed, the problem reduces to finding the minimum value of 
$$f(\theta) = ( 1+\csc\theta)^2 \tan \theta$$

This is a straightforward (if a bit tedious) calculus problem, and the answer will turn out to be $\theta = 30^\circ$.

Answer (score -1):

Watch this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZCYaVY1kXc&ab_channel=Tick%2CBoom%21). He shows you to get to the answer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).